# Piranha CMS and Azure Storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-blob-storage, piranha-cms

I am currently evaluating Piranha CMS and I like what I see so far.  The only real concern I have is how binary assets are managed.  Does the image upload support storing images on CDN like amazond s3 or Azure Blob Storage?  If so, how is that accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

There are currently both Media & MediaCache providers available for Azure Blob Storage in the Piranha.Azure project. The only reason that this hasn't been released on NuGet yet (like the issue from the previous post says) is that the package as a whole hasn't been fully tested.

It would also be fairly easy to write a database based MediaProvider if you wish to store binary files in the database, it all depends on what you want to acheive.

For a simple web site (Azure WebSites) the standard behaviour store binary files in the App_Data folder is sufficient, however for a more distributed environment binary files should be moved to a more centralized location!

Comment: Wouldn't storing the media files in App_Data cause them to be deleted/overwritten each time you deploy?  Especially if you're using Deployment Slots in Websites Standard?

Comment: In my opinion it's a matter how you deploy it. You can store media anywhere you want by overriding the Local Media provider. But I'll take a look at the default settings of the Azure Deploy mechanism!

Answer (score 0):

please checkout media handler. https://github.com/tidyui/Piranha/issues/133